# Graphs in which each vertex is of degree larger than $\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: graph-theory

I was wondering if anyone can direct me to results on simple graphs for which each vertex degree is larger than $\frac{n}{2}$ where $n$ is the number of the vertices. I wonder if this type of graphs have a name and/or have been studied.

I will be very grateful.

Comment: Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dense_graph?

Comment: Thank you Joshua, this will certainly help.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes such graphs are called [Dirac's graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.00742.pdf) or [Dirac's family of graphs](https://eudml.org/doc/270422) referring to Dirac's theorem:

> **Theorem** (Dirac, 1952) A simple graph with $n$ vertices ($n \geq 3$) is Hamiltonian if every vertex has degree $\tfrac{n}{2}$ or greater.

Comment: Further adding on, Ore's theorem states that if all $u, v$ in a graph G have the property such that $d(u) + d(v) \geq n$, then G is hamiltonian.

Comment: The above implies Dirac's.

Comment: @Iamaperson It [has been generalized](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X12005171) in many different ways, however every of them gives another (wider) class of graphs. I wrote about class from the question only